# Extract() from Postgres to calculate minutes between 2 columns

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, extract

Want to calculate minutes between to columns with start_time and end_time as timestamp without zone for two customers types, and then averange the result for each.

I tried to use extract() by using the following statement, but can't get the right result:

```
select avg(duration_minutes) 
from ( 
  select started_at,ended_at, extract('minute' from (started_at - ended_at)) as duration_minutes 
  from my_data 
  where customer_type = 'member' 
) avg_duration;
```

Result:

| avg |
| --- |
| 0.000 |

This run sucessfuly in BQ using the following:

```
select avg(duration_minutes) from
(
  select started_at,ended_at,
  datetime_diff(ended_at,started_at, minute) as duration_minutes
  from my_table
  where customer_type = "member"
) avg_duration
```

Result:

| f0_ |
| --- |
| 21.46 |

Wondering what might be failing in postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extract(minute from ...)` extracts the *field* with the minutes from the interval. So if the interval is "1 hour 26 minutes and 45 seconds" the result would be `26` not 86.

To convert an interval to the equivalent number of minutes, extract the total number of seconds using `extract(epoch ...)` and multiply that with 60.

```
select avg(duration_minutes) 
from ( 
  select started_at,
         ended_at, 
         extract(epoch from (started_at - ended_at)) * 60 as duration_minutes 
  from my_data 
  where customer_type = 'member' 
) avg_duration;
```

---

Note that you can calculate the average of an interval without the need to convert it to minutes:

```
select avg(duration) 
from ( 
  select started_at,
         ended_at, 
         started_at - ended_at as duration
  from my_data 
  where customer_type = 'member' 
) avg_duration;
```

Depending on how you use the result, returning an `interval` might be more useful. You can also convert *that* to minutes using:

```
extract(epoch from avg(duration)) * 60 as average_minutes
```